# Elastic Search: Matching fields in different nested objects

Tags: search

I am new to Elastic Search and this is my user index:

```
{
"user": {
"properties": {
  "branches": {
    "type": "nested"
  },
  "lists": {
    "type": "nested"
  },
  "events": {
    "type": "nested"
  },
  "optOuts": {
    "type": "nested"
  }
}
}
}
```

Here, branches, events and lists will contain the field id(int),countryIso(String)..

I need to find users having emails who belong to countryIso 'XX' for example.

```
{
"query": {
"bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "exists": {
        "field": "email"
      }
    },
    {
      "match": {
        "prog_id": 3
      }
    },
    {
      "nested": {
        "path": [
          "branches"
        ],
        "query": {
          "query_string": {
            "fields": [
              "branches.countryIso"
            ],
            "query": "AE KW"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
}
}
```

This way I can get them if they have that country in the branches object. What I want is that the countryIso is there in the branches or lists or events. 
Note: any of these might be empty i.e. branches may not be there or lists miht not be there etc. Or lists might be there with no countryIso..

I tried this:

```
{
 "query": {
"bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "exists": {
        "field": "email"
      }
    },
    {
      "match": {
        "prog_id": 3
      }
    },
    {
      "nested": {
        "path": [
          "branches"
        ],
        "query": {
          "query_string": {
            "fields": [
              "branches.countryIso"
            ],
            "query": "AE KW"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "nested": {
        "path": [
          "lists"
        ],
        "query": {
          "query_string": {
            "fields": [
              "lists.countryIso"
            ],
            "query": "AE KW"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
}
}
```

AND

```
{
"query": {
"bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "exists": {
        "field": "email"
      }
    },
    {
      "match": {
        "prog_id": 3
      }
    },
    {
      "nested": {
        "path": [
          "branches",
          "lists"
        ],
        "query": {
          "query_string": {
            "fields": [
              "branches.countryIso",
              "lists.countryIso"
            ],
            "query": "AE KW"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
 }
}
```

But neither works.